# React create a reusable Modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm new using React and I'm trying to create a reusable Modal element.

My Modal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

export const errorModal = (data) => {
    const show = true;

    const handleCloseErrorModal = () => show = false;

    return (
        <Modal show={show} onHide={this.handleCloseErrorModal}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>{data.title}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>{data.body}</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleCloseErrorModal}>
                    Close
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    );
};
```

Then, I call it in a class component. I have a method that tries to login. If it fails, I would like to call my modal

```
import { errorModal } from '../Util/Modal';

// Some code here until I get to the part that calls the modal

let stData = {
    title: 'Error',
    body: 'Invalid email/username'
};
errorModal(stData);
```

It is returning the error:

```
TypeError: undefined has no properties
    errorModal Modal.js:11
    loginClick Login.js:63
    promise callback*Login/this.loginClick Login.js:54
    React 17
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:653
    React 23
    js index.js:11
    Webpack 7
```

Login.js line 63 is where I call errorModal(stData)

Comment: Okay. You need to learn the basics of `React` before starting. I recommend watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0). You're way off on implementation and the foundations on React. Invest your time in that video, and later if you have any problem, feel free to post.

Comment: Thank you for video, but my question was related to the issue I posted. Do you know what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Again, rather than telling you what is wrong with your code. You should learn the basics and then you'll find out. I see no point in correcting you, it might solve your problem but it would be better if you solve it yourself after going through the basics.